# Is there a way to change the default Android Permissions Message

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, android-permissions

I'm creating an app that will require several permissions from users, mainly internet access for crash reports. However internet would only be used to submit said crash reports and nothing else. I want to inform the user when they install the app that this is the only reason the app needs internet access, I ideally want to do this by changing the default permissions message that comes up when installing the app. Is it possible to change the default permission message or is it not accessible? I'm currently building the app in Android Studio

Comment: Will be possible in android M, with `permissionRationale`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. The only thing you can do to display your own dialog before showing the default permission popup.
So for example if you need to read contacts, you can show your own dialog convincing them about sharing contacts in your own words and asking them to accept in next dialog.

This is only workaround :)

Comment: Yeah thats what I was thinking. I'll just have to do that then. Thanks